# Hive Join stuck at Map stage

Tags: hive, hiveql

In Hive, I have a large table `B` (~300 Million rows) and a relative small table `A`. I am simply trying to do 

`SELECT A.*, B.* FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.a_id = B.b_id`

but the query is stuck at map 50% and does not progress. I also tried to do the same operation in PySpark but basically had same outcome. Both `a_id` and `b_id` are strings and they are unique keys for `A` and `B`, respectively. In order to perform the join, instead of selecting `A.*` and `B.*`, I had to pick only the columns I absolutely need for my current analysis. Even though now this join can complete, could anyone please give me some more in-depth insight of why I had this problem? Is it simply the size of table being too large for the worker memory?

Comment: what is the data size in table A and file format for both tables?

Comment: @SandeepSingh  `A` is only ~40k rows, both `A` and `B` are text format. `A` raw size is ~30M.

Comment: Can you please also check the default execution engine for your Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `select *`, all table data are getting scanned. Again one table has fewer records hence appropriate resources are not getting assigned and hence it is getting stuck due to unavailability of the resource.

Enabling map join and increasing heap memory should help in solving this problem. You can enable these by setting below property before the query.

```
set mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx7200m;
set hive.auto.convert.join = true;
```